# How often is MobilePush SDK data synced back to Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush

As the title states, I want to know how often does the MobilePush SDK sync back data to Marketing Cloud?

> For example, if I create a custom attribute in MobilePush Demographics
>   and populate it with information from my App. after how much time
>   would that data be available in my Contact (MobilePush Demographics)
>   information?

Any documentation is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the github '[Registration Updates Via Contact Key, Attributes, and Tags](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html)'

> The SDK will send changes to the Marketing Cloud servers within one minute of the first change to any Marketing Cloud Mobile Push device or contact registration record and no more frequently than once per minute after as required. This can be data set by your application like Contact Key, Tags or Attributes or it could be system related and set by the SDK like Time Zone, Locale or Application Version, etc.
>
> If the registration update fails the SDK will retry using a backoff algorithm with increasing retry intervals to a maximum delay of 1 day at which point the SDK will retry daily until it is successful.
>
> It will take up to 5 minutes for the registration data to be propagated throughout the Marketing Cloud servers and services once the REST call is successfully completed by the SDK.